# How to wait for the child activity to finish

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to make a phonegap/cordova plugin which is for converting speech to text using  RecognizerIntent. The following is my code of the plugin class:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    try {
        if (ACTION_INVOKE_SPEECH_RECOG.equals(action)) { 

            //JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);

            Intent calIntent =  new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            calIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            this.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(SpeechToTextPlugin.this);
            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(calIntent,REQUEST_CODE );
            callbackContext.success("Completed Main Activity");

        }
        callbackContext.error("Invalid action");
        return false;
       } catch(Exception e) {
           System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
           callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
           return false;

    } 
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

          try {
              //obj.put("TEXT", intent.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS).toString());
              callbackContext.success(intent.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS).toString());

          }catch(JSONException e){

          }
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      }
}
```

I pass the recognized text to the javascript invoking the execute method. Right now, after making a call to `startActivityForResult`, the execute function returns back. How do I pass the recognized word to the js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
sendJavascript("yourJSClass.yourJSMethod();");
```

or just

```
sendJavascript("yourJSMethod();");
```

Of course you will have to have:

```
yourJSMethod = function() {}
```

in your JS